# JButton over JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jscrollpane

I have such piece of code which shoud add button over `JTextArea` placed in `JScrollPane`. Button isn't inside scroll pane!

```
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setBounds(10, 340, 375, 242);
    contentPane.add(scrollPane);

    JButton btnClean = new JButton();
    btnClean.setBounds(340, 341, 26, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnClean);

    taLog = new JTextArea();
    taLog.setEditable(false);
    taLog.setLineWrap(true);
    taLog.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    scrollPane.setViewportView(taLog);

    epInfo = new JEditorPane();
    epInfo.putClientProperty(JEditorPane.HONOR_DISPLAY_PROPERTIES, Boolean.TRUE);
    epInfo.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    epInfo.setContentType("text/html");
    epInfo.setEditable(false);
    epInfo.setBackground(null);
    epInfo.setBorder(null);
    epInfo.setBounds(10, 241, 375, 37);
    setInfoText();
    contentPane.add(epInfo);
```

Problem is whenever `JTextArea` changes its value button is not refreshed - it just dissapears - until I will drag mouse cursor over it. I suppose then some `repaint()` is launched.
I figured out I can add `DocumentListener` to `JTextArea` and there manually refresh button but it works until scroll bar appears in `JScrollPane`.
I can also use

```
scrollPane.getViewport().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
{}});
```

but it is invoked many times and all those refreshes are not neccesary.
Is there any reasonable (and efficient) way to check if `JScrollPane` changed?

[image]

Comment: Don't use a null layout. Don't use setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. I can't suggest which layout manger to use because I don't understand your desired layout. Post and image or use ascii art to demonstrate your desired layout.

Comment: @camickr Null layout is useful in this case because main window is fixed. Also I use WindowBuilder in Eclipse then I don't place XY manually.
I've added picture. Button is in red circle.

Answer (score 0):

> Null layout is useful in this case because main window is fixed

No it is not useful.

Any time you code uses random numbers (ie to set the size/location) of components) the code is not easily maintainable.

> Also I use WindowBuilder

Code generated by an IDE is not maintainable in another IDE.

Learn to use layout managers. The point of using layout managers is to avoid hard coding of numbers and to make the code maintainable in any environment.

> Problem is whenever JTextArea changes its value button is not refreshed

```
contentPane.add(scrollPane);
...
contentPane.add(btnClean);
```

Swing is designed to display components in two dimension when added to the same container.

If you want components displayed in two dimension then you need to have a parent / child relationship:

```
- content pane
    - text area
        button
```

So the code should be something like:

```
textArea.setLayout( new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT) );
//contentPane.add(btnClean);
textArea.add(btnClean);
```

Note: you can configure the FlowLayout to remove the spacing on the top and right.

The problem with this is that the button will cover any text that displayed in the text area.

So the better solution is to make the button external to the text area.

Comment: About null layout: yes, it is useful. I mean not as a solution of this specific problem, but in general. Coordinates are not random - i don't understand why you say so. I don't care it is not maintainable in another IDE (but in fact it is absolutely maintanable because WindowBuilder generates pure and clean java code in contradiction to eg. NetBeans). Please understand I know other types of layouts (of course not all of them) and I want to use null one. Anyway this is not the main subject.
Adding button to text area is not a solution because it will be scrolled with whole field.

Comment: *i don't understand why you say so* - and that is the problem. You don't understand how Swing was designed to work and how layout manager make maintenance of the code easier. For example what if the text of your label changes, the size of the label will also change. What if you want a different font size? Then the size and location of all components will need to be changed. Scrolling won't work when you use a null layout. *Anyway this is not the main subject* - yes it is an issue because of all the time we spend answering questions related to issues caused by null layouts. Use Swing properly!

Comment: *it will be scrolled with whole field* -  Maybe you can use an `OverlayLayout`. I've never tried it for something like this but it is designed to allow multiple components to be displayed on top of one another. If not,  well like I said, the better solution is to make the button external to the text area, this is the way the UI is usually designed.

Comment: Please, stop talking about null layout. I know all problems you mentioned and I agree with you. I also understand meaning of layers. Problem is you don't understand I WANT null layout in contentPane no matter how Swing was designed and agree with all limitation pointet by you. There is also possibility we talk about two different things and you try to tell me scrollPane inherits layout type from its parent which is contentPane if I will not set it in it manually? Then indeed it can be a problem. I will try OverlayLayout.

Comment: Or maybe you try point my attention to fact null layout handle overlaying different (not handling?) than other layouts?

Comment: My point is Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Until the problem is solved, you don't know if the null layout is or isn't the problem. If you WANT us to look at your code, then post proper code that is easy to read and follows Swing standards (to reduce the possibility of errors). We are not here to help solve problems because you won't use Swing the way it was intended to be used. Even attempting a add a button in the viewport is a non standard UI. As a user I would be frustrated to see the text hide under the button. The button should be external to the scrollpane.

Comment: Another option is to add the button to the top/left corner of the scroll pane. Then is will be considered part of the scroll pane since it will be included in the border. Of course you would also need to add a dummy component as the header of the scroll pane.